1970s? Novel, a man is stuck/trapped? in a city where the other people are fooled/conned into believing things are better than they are
MC appears to be trapped in a city, where everything is in poor condition but the inhabitants don't know how bad everything is. This was not a mystery type story, there was some sci-fi aspect as to why he was there.
For example (not from the story): a gallon of milk is only the size of a half gallon, but labeled 1 gallon, and the people believe it IS a gallon. Or they're wearing clothes that have labels saying Armani or Gucci or Prada, and the people think they are, but the MC can see they are of a quality of Levi's denims blue jeans.
The only specific thing I recall in the story is: The MC catches a ride with someone in their car. The driver is bragging about the quality of the car (a Cadillac or Mercedes style) and how fast it is. He steps on the gas (or the MC asks him to go faster) and goes up to say 120MPH on the speedometer, and you can hear the wind shrieking as the car flies down the roadway. But, the MC feels like the car has the quality of a Volkswagen, cant be going faster than about 40mph, and the wind noise is coming from small speakers on the dash. The driver eventually slows down, very nervous, afraid he will crash if he keeps going that fast.
I do not remember much more than that from the story. Other than the vague feeling that the MC had been placed there and was trying to get out. (Similar to the old BBC program "The Prisoner") But unlike "The Prisoner" where most of the inhabitants had just accepted their life there and were content with maintaining the status quo, the inhabitants of the city where the MC was, were clueless. (It had gone on so long, they did not realize how bad everything was or how they had been fooled.)

Just had another flash of memory, not sure if its the same story, But MC goes to a barber to get a haircut and the barber tells him its the first time he has seen an old man with grey hair with dark roots. (He is actually a younger man, and whoever placed him there has died his hair grey so he looks old. They may have also done something to his body so he feels old, but it is gradually wearing off)


"The Prisoner" was British, but broadcast on ITV and distributed (worldwide) by ITC, not BBC

Not an answer because many of the specific details don't fit, but the general theme fits Stanislaw Lem's Futurological Congress, where the main character is cryogenically frozen, and wakes up in a future where everything looks like an utopia, but only because the government releases psychoactive substances in the air, so people perceive reality as looking much better than it really is. People walk around in ragged clothes believing they are of high quality, eat porridge in ramshackle diners and believe they are eating gourmet food in a prestigious restaurant, etc.

The bit about the cars sounds like it's from The Marching Morons (1951) by Cyril M. Kornbluth; you can read it in Galaxy, April 1951 or a Project Gutenberg

The psychist climbed down into the driver's seat and did something with his feet. The motor started like lighting a blowtorch as big as a silo. Wallowing around in the cushions, Barlow saw through a rear-view mirror a tremendous exhaust filled with brilliant white sparkles.
"Do you like it?" yelled the psychist.
"It's terrific!" Barlow yelled back. "It's—"
He was shut up as the car pulled out from the bay into the road with a great voo-ooo-ooom! A gale roared past Barlow's head, though the windows seemed to be closed; the impression of speed was terrific. He located the speedometer on the dashboard and saw it climb past 90, 100, 150, 200.

But it's a con:

Watching them, Barlow began to wonder if he knew what a kilometer was, exactly. They seemed to be traveling so slowly, if you ignored the roaring air past your ears and didn't let the speedy lines of the dreamboats fool you. He would have sworn they were really crawling along at twenty-five, with occasional spurts up to thirty. How much was a kilometer, anyway?

Which is confirmed by Tinny-Peete, the psychist:

The automobiles have a top speed of one hundred kilometers per hour—a kilometer is, if I recall my paleolinguistics, three-fifths of a mile—and the speedometers are all rigged accordingly so the drivers will think they're going two hundred and fifty.


Note that the rest of your points don't match, but this is a very strong match for the car bit.  It's possible you've read one of the many collections that contain this story, and are conflating different stories.

It isn't quite what I remember, but close enough. I suspect I read it in Omni Magazine, as I was a avid read of Omni in the early 80s. (The wind noise starting and stopping not matching up with the movement of the car is what makes me pretty sure this is the story.)  The bit with the barber has to be from another story.
